# Room : select query doesn't retrieve an object's attribute

Tags: android, android-room

My android app is offering user accounts. A User is represnetd by the following class :

```
public class User implements Parcelable {
    @NonNull
    @ColumnInfo(name = "user_Id")
    @PrimaryKey (autoGenerate = true)
    private Long userId;
    private String displayedName;
    private String email;
    private String password;
    @ColumnInfo(name = "photo_Id")
    private Long photoId;
```

The PhotoId references the Photo :

```
public class Photo implements Parcelable {
    @NonNull
    @ColumnInfo(name = "photo_Id")
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    private Long photoId;
    private String image;
```

When I save a user account, I save the user, then save the photo and finally update the user whith the photo id generated. I use theses queries :

```
    @Insert
    Single<Long> insert(User user);
    @Update
    Completable update (User user);
    @Insert
    Single<Long> insert(Photo photo);
```

The creation process seems 100% successful accpording to the logs, but when I retrieve a user from the DB with

```
    @Query("SELECT * FROM User WHERE email = :userEmail")
    Single<User> getUserByEmail(String userEmail);
```

I retrieve a user with a null photoId.
How could I debug this and find if the user photoId is not correctly updated in the DB por if the user select query doesn't create a complete User ?

---

Update : the problem is that the User has no photId in the DB even after update.

Comment: use https://github.com/amitshekhariitbhu/Android-Debug-Database to debug db

Comment: Do you assign the photoId manually to the user after creating both of them?

Comment: Yes I update the User with the generated photoId after User and Photo creation.

Comment: Thanks Rasel, I can see that this is the User that is not correctly updated with the photoId. I edit my first message.

Comment: Can you share the code that shows how you are getting the photo id after inserting the photo? Also, what does the user update code/query look like?